# Django-admin dynamics variables

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views, django-admin

```
% block content %}
  <div id="content-main" class="inner-two-columns">

    <form {% if has_file_field %}enctype="multipart/form-data" {% endif %}action="{{ form_url }}" method="post"
          id="{% firstof opts.model_name opts.module_name %}_form" class="form-horizontal" novalidate>

      <div class="inner-right-column">

        <div class="box save-box">

          {% block submit_buttons_bottom %}{% submit_row %}{% endblock %}
          <input type="submit" value="Kaydet ve Kapat">
        </div>
```

i just wondering where is coming from these variables such as {submit_button_bottom} {submit_row}. I couldnt find anything about these variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`submit_buttons_bottom` is a block defined in the template that is inherited using `{% extends %}` and `{% submit_row %}` is a template tag that was loaded using `{% load something %}`.

Note that both should occur at the top of the file and that what was loaded is usually not be called `submit_row` but has a different name like `something`. Read more about template tags [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/custom-template-tags/).